# How to close sftp connections made by dolphin?

Tags: kubuntu, ssh, dolphin, sftp, scp

after using dolphin to connect to a ssh site, for example:

sftp://myserver.com

and using my user and pass... how can I close that connection so I can log in with another user? It does always auto log me in with that same user

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to type in the username, e.g. jondoe, into the url, like this:

```
sftp://jondoe@myserver.com
```

However, my attempts with sftp failed. I used fish:// instead to get it to work. Like this:

```
fish://jondoe@myserver.com
```

Comment: It's `fish://` indeed, but it doesn't answer his question.